# How to open php with POST method?

Tags: php, vb.net

How can I open/redirect to my PHP(URL), below is my code. thanks.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Dim postData As String = "submit=submit&amountPrice=1.50"
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/payment/process.php")
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
    MsgBox(responseFromServer)

End Sub
```

The above code is for send POST to my PHP and read the respond in `MsgBox`, but I cannot open the URL. How can I do this?

Comment: Define _"cannot open the url"_. Any errors? If so, what are the error messages and where?

Comment: There is no error, I can receive the response on my msgbox. I need to redirect to my Post url, is the any missing code?

Comment: I don't get it, what is the problem then?? Isn't `/payment/process.php` your post URL?

Comment: Vincent, I can open the process.php on webbrowser now, change MsgBox(responseFromServer) to WebBrowser1.DocumentText = responseFromServer, but it's open in webbrowser, my next concern is can we open the response in default browser i/o webbrowser? please advice me the code? thanks

Comment: Define _"default browser i/o webbrowser"_. -- Seeing as you put the response in a WebBrowser control I can only assume that the response is HTML code?

Comment: If you mean the web browser application that the user has set as his default, you'd have to save the response to a `.html` file and then open it using `Process.Start("file path here")`.